# ASP.NET Core Identity - How to add new claims after initial login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity, claims, iprincipal

I am trying to add new claims to the Identity after the initial login based on certain data that is queried from database. The new claims that I am adding not persisting for subsequent requests.

This is how i'm setting/Adding claims in ASP.NET MVC

```
public static void UpdateClaim(IPrincipal principal, string key, string value)
        {
            var identity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (identity == null)
                return;

            // check for existing claim and remove it
            var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst(key);
            if (existingClaim != null)
                identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);

            // add new claim
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(key, value));
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
        }
```

Is there is similar way in ASP.NET Core 2.0 to persist newly added claims. Appreciate any ideas on this.

Answer (score 2):

The claims are persisting, but they are only loaded when signing in. If you make a change to something like claims or roles, you must sign the user out and then either automatically sign them back in or prompt them to reauthenticated to update the claims.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to refresh the user's sign-in, because Identity caches their claims upon sign-in for performance reasons.

In several pages from a scaffolded Identity integration, this line is used:

`await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);`

You can see the (sparse) documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.refreshsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The concept is explained a bit here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-and-update-user-claims

> call SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync on a user to force the generation of a new authentication cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Claims are not persisting if you are simply adding claims in Claims identity object in asp core, either you will have to use iClaimsTransformation or ClaimAction,

Comment: Please post the relevant info here instead of referring to a blog. Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem, stackoverflow meant to help technical aspirants notwithstanding the mode, my sole intention is to help

Comment: Glad to hear your intention is to help. Problem is exactly whet @piraces said - the *relevant information* should be in the answer. This is to not have any dead links at any point in the future, as a dead link is not helpful at all.